# Changing colors for Xamarin.Forms Material Visual

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, material-design

When I am using the **Xamrin.Forms Material Visual** the **primary** color of the controls like the button, entries and so on is set to **black**. How do I change this presetting? Is there an option **without overriding the renderers** or did I have to override the renderers?
Options like **changing the primary color** in the **App.xaml** or changing the **Theme** in the **MainActivity.cs** I have **already tried**. As well I have searched for solutions in the web, but in all samples the primary color is set to black.

MainActivity.cs:

```
[Activity(Label = "Test", Icon = "@mipmap/TestLogo", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
```

styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#082070</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#082070</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#b4ffa2</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#b4ffa2</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test_App.App">
    <!--
        Define global resources and styles here, that apply to all pages in your app.
    -->
    <Application.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#082070</Color>
        <Color x:Key="SecondaryColor">#b4ffa2</Color>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Visual" Value="Material"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Visual" Value="Material"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="Visual" Value="Material"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Visual" Value="Material"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="Visual" Value="Material"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Editor">
            <Setter Property="Visual" Value="Material"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Picker">
            <Setter Property="Visual" Value="Material"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
            <Setter Property="Visual" Value="Material"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TimePicker">
            <Setter Property="Visual" Value="Material"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code of your MainActivity.cs and App.xaml, the color won't work if the theme name doesn't match.

Comment: @Shaw Does the theme name match?